# How to define CSS style for ALL types of SVG'S structure?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, sass

I have many SVG's on my page, that I imported as (in React):

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "./../../../images/example.svg";
```

And them I use them this way:

```
<div className='someClassName activeClassName?'>
  <Logo />
</div>
```

But all of them are different in their structure.
What do I mean? Some of SVG's are looks like:

```
<svg>
  <path/>
</svg>
```

some like:

```
<svg>
  <g>
     <g>
        <path/>
     </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

some looks like:

```
<svg>
  <g>
     <circle/> 
     <triangle/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And there are millions of types like this.
I have a 'activeClassName' which fill SVG in different color, when it's active, but to make it work with all my SVG's, I have to describe my classname styles kinda like this:

```
&--active {
      svg {
        fill: $primaryBlue !important;
        path {
          fill: $primaryBlue !important;
        }
        g {
          fill: $primaryBlue !important;
          g path {
            fill: $primaryBlue !important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This looks awful. How can I change, for example, the fill option for all of those SVG's? Please, help me... thanks

Comment: Are the fill attribute already defined on all/some for the elements?

Comment: @chrwahl, they are different at all, some of them defined fill, some not, some defined height, some not
That's why I am struggling with "How to define one style for all of them?"
That's weird

Comment: Edit them and remove the fill attributes that you want to override.

Comment: @RobertLongson, is there no way to automatize this? Should I edit every SVG element that I am using in React? This looks weird, frankly speaking

Comment: OK, do it the way you're currently doing then.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I do not doubt in your resolve this problem, thank you for your answer, I really appreciate that
I just don't want to stop on this solution, maybe there's something more elegant?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Robert Longson and @chrwahl pointed out:
removing fill attributes from your svg child elements is recommended.
Not sure, how you could "pre/postprocess" your imported svg component.

In plain js you could easily query your child elements and remove attributes like so:

```js
let svgAsset = document.querySelector(".svgAsset");
// query child elements – maybe includeother svg primitives like circles/rects
let svgChildEls = svgAsset.querySelectorAll("g, path, circle, rect, polygon");


function removeFills(els = svgChildEls) {
  els.forEach(function (el, i) {
      el.removeAttribute("fill");
  });
}

function addElClass(els = svgChildEls) {
  els.forEach(function (el, i) {
    let nodeName = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if(nodeName!='g'){
       el.classList.add("svgChild");
    }
  });
}

function toggleActive(){
  svgAsset.classList.toggle('svgActive');
  svgAsset.classList.toggle('svgInactive');
}
```

```css
svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
}

/* inactive */
.svgInactive{
    fill: #ccc;
}

.svgActive{
  fill: orange;
}

.svgActive
.svgChild{
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="toggleActive()">toggle active</button>
  <button onclick="removeFills()">Remove fill attributes</button>
  <button onclick="addElClass()">Add element Class</button>
</p>
<div class="svgWrp">
  <svg class="svgAsset svgInactive" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path id="path0" fill="red" d="M0 0 l50 0 l0 50 l-50 0 z" />
    <path id="path1" class="hasClass" fill="green" d="M33 33 l50 0 l0 50 l-50 0 z" />
    <g fill="purple">
      <circle id="" cx="66.666%" cy="33.333%" r="25%" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

In the above example I've also included `<g>` elements and other shape primitives like polygons:

```
let svgChildEls = svgAsset.querySelectorAll("g, path, circle, rect, polygon");
```

You benefit from a lower css specificity – so you don't need nested selectors like

`svg g path{ ... }`

Manually checking and optimizing your svg source material is always the best approach, since you can't expect graphics from different sources to have a coherent structure.
E.g svgs generated by GUI applications tend to have slightly quirky markup including way to many `<g>` nesting, unsused or too many transforms (making it hard to get or manipulate x/y offsets) etc.